# Where is the ListProduct.php under Magento\CatalogSearch\Block\SearchResult?

Tags: magento2, search

Where is the `ListProduct.php` under `Magento\CatalogSearch\Block\SearchResult`? I can't find it under the source code folder.

Comment: Where are you getting this? There's no sign of any such class or path in the Magento 2.0 core (master/releases or develop).

Comment: Please check this file path "Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct.php"

Comment: Okay..? I don't understand your problem. There are no references to `Magento\CatalogSearch` within that class.

Answer (score 11):

Let me answer it by myself. I can't find the `ListProduct.php` under `Magento\CatalogSearch\Block\SearchResult` because it is a virtual type which will be redirected to `Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct.php` due to the `di.xml` under `Magento\CatalogSearch\etc\frontend\di.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

    <!--
    /**
     * Copyright © 2015 Magento. All rights reserved.
     * See COPYING.txt for license details.
     */
    -->
    <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
        <virtualType name="Magento\CatalogSearch\Model\Session\Storage" type="Magento\Framework\Session\Storage">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="namespace" xsi:type="string">catalogsearch</argument>
            </arguments>
        </virtualType>
        <virtualType name="Magento\CatalogSearch\Model\Session" type="Magento\Framework\Session\Generic">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="storage" xsi:type="object">Magento\CatalogSearch\Model\Session\Storage</argument>
            </arguments>
        </virtualType>
        <virtualType name="Magento\CatalogSearch\Block\SearchResult\ListProduct" type="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="catalogLayer" xsi:type="object">Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\Search</argument>
            </arguments>
        </virtualType>
    </config>
```